# Where can I find the solutions to exercises of Probabilistic Graphical Models?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, probabilistic-method, bayesian-network

I am self-learning *Probabilistic Graphical Models* written by Daphne Koller. And for testing   how well I learned, I did the exercises in the textbook. But I have no solutions to these exercises. Can anybody give me a copy of the solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I reckon the course is hard and some of the exercises are a bit intractable, but I really hope that no solutions show up on the Internet, or it will most likely ruin Coursera's ranking system. Also it's probably contrary to Coursera's Honor Code.

Comment: I partially agree with you. For a self-learner, however, solutions are very useful for him to check whether he really understands what he learned by doing exercises. And other courses like *Convex Optimization* have provided all materials(including textbook, exercises and solutions) on the Internet.

Comment: Understandable, but I think this is then up to each course organiser to choose his/her way. Also I suspect that some of these exercises are used in the Stanford class, which would be another reason to avoid leaking solutions.

Comment: OP is specifically referring to the text book and not to the course